# How to install xwobf on Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, lockscreen

I've been trying to install `xwobf` to use it with `i3lock` using this github project https://github.com/glindste/xwobf. But it doesn't work and there is to few information on the github discussion and README.md. Could you please try to help me ? I've tried to clone the repository and then tried to `make` then `make install` but it throws this error :

```
cc -Wall -std=c99 `pkg-config --cflags MagickWand xcb` -O3 -c xwobf.c
Package MagickWand was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `MagickWand.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'MagickWand' found
Package xcb was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `xcb.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'xcb' found
xwobf.c:28:21: fatal error: xcb/xcb.h: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
 #include <xcb/xcb.h>
                     ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [xwobf.o] Erreur 1
```

So I've tried to download MagickWand and XCB but there was always errors.
Thank you for reading this.

**EDIT :**

I managed to install the good library : `libmagickwand-dev` so I don't have that many errors. But I now have a single one :

```
cc -Wall -std=c99 `pkg-config --cflags MagickWand xcb` -O3 -c xwobf.c
xwobf.c:29:35: fatal error: MagickWand/MagickWand.h: Aucun fichier ou 
dossier de ce type
#include <MagickWand/MagickWand.h>
                               ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [xwobf.o] Erreur 1
```

Comment: `MagickWand.h` : Install `libmagickwand-6-headers` ... and edit `xwobf.c` line 29 to `#include <ImageMagick-6/wand/MagickWand.h>` ... About `xcb/xcb.h` : Install `libxcb1-dev`.

Comment: He cannot find the package `libmagickwand-6-headers`

Comment: The install command is `sudo apt update && sudo apt install libmagickwand-6-headers` ... https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/libmagickwand-6-headers

Comment: That is what I did. But still he cannot find the package...

Comment: Please read https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/libmagickwand-6-headers ... Can you install the dependency `libmagickcore-6-headers`? ... Else: Download the packages, and install with `sudo gdebi Downloads/[packages.deb]`